# align a clip to the left of the stage on resize with flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get my clip to stay at the left of the screen on stage resize, but it isn't working. This is my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);

function resizeHandler(e:Event){
      circleMenu.x = 0;
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but how do you get the global zero X position. When I resize the window, my clip moves along with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that does work, but you need to initialize your stage properly. In fact if you do this, you won't have to tell your clip to stay to the left at all. Somewhere in initialization do this:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Your object appears to be moving because the clip is being scaled and/or the alignment is set to the default (which I believe is middle or center).

Comment: 2.5 years later, I guess you took some time to think about this :)

Comment: I did. I went on a walk about, I took a great deep inward journey while I lived in the mountains, breathing, eating and drinking your words. Then one day not so long ago I awoke and suddenly I had a response for you.